# Need delay in between POSTs in JavaScript loop iterations

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, get, delay

I have a json file and I am iterating over its contents and using a HTTP post request for each iteration. The POST request inserts info in a database. I need to introduce a delay either in the loop or somehow in between the POSTs. What I have now is this:

```
var request = require('request');

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    request.post(
        'http://localhost:3000/post',
        { form: { from: arr[i][0], to: arr[i][1]} },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(body)
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Currently, the POST requests are called pretty much instantaneously after one another, which poses a problem for some of the DB insertion logic that requires some time in between. Does anyone have a good idea as to how to implement a delay?

Thank you

Comment: I would rather rewrite the application to support the full `arr` request. (the insert operation). introducing a delay seems hacky

Comment: Instead of making assumptions about a delay which _might_ work, I would make use of callbacks or promises and make the posts sequentially

Comment: see my answer for Johan's suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you've got is you're mixing synchronous (loop) and asynchronous (request) operations.

There is no mechanism for making the outer loop wait for inner, asynchronous operations to complete before continuing to the next iteration.

Instead you could implement recursion, requiring the callback function to instigate the next iteration of the outer "loop".

```
function do_post_req(arr_key) {
    request.post(
        'http://localhost:3000/post',
        { form: { from: arr[i][0], to: arr[i][1]} },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(body);
                if (arr[key+1]) do_post_req(key+1); //<-- recursion
            }
        }
    );
}
do_post_req(0); //<-- kick things off with first array key
```

Comment: +1, though you might want to move your recursive call outside of the if statement to keep going despite errors

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure if the OP wanted to break the loop on error, so I left that to him.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `setTimeout`? It seems hacky though.

```
var interval = 10;
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        request.post(
            'http://localhost:3000/post',
            { form: { from: arr[i][0], to: arr[i][1]} },
            function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    console.log(body)
                }
            }
        );
    }, i * interval);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use timers:

```
var interval = 1000;
function doPosts() {
    if (arr.length == 0)
       return;
    data = arr.pop();
    request.post(
        'http://localhost:3000/post',
        { form: { from: data[0], to: data[1]} },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(body)
            }
        }
    );
    setTimeout(doPosts, interval);
}
doPosts();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the async module for node https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback

Adding manual sleeps/waits is a bad idea since theres always a chance a callback takes longer  than the manual time you set or fails.

```
var request = require('request');
var async = require('async');

async.each(arr, 
  function(arri, cb) {
     request.post(
        'http://localhost:3000/post',
        { form: { from: arri[0], to: arri[1]} },
        function (error, response, body) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(body);
                // do you insert stuff here before the cb() call so its done before the next request is executed
                // if the insert stuff is asynchronous as well call cb() inside the callback of your insert
                cb();
            } else {
                cb(error); // only do this if you want to stop at error
            }
        }
    );
  }, 
  function(err) {
    if (err) { console.log(err); }
    else { console.log("all done"); }
  });
```

if you want to run the requests parallel have a look at the parallel method of async.